# Non-Observant Jew Staying At An Observant Jew’s Home On Shabbath

Tags: halacha, shabbat

If a non-observant Jew were to go out and buy something on the Shabbath, while staying at an observant Jews home, is that item(s) allowed within their home on the Shabbath?

Comment: I don't think this question is a duplicate. This question asks if the item is allowed in the home and the other question asks about the benefit from malacha.